# How to return HTML directly from a Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One of my model objects has a 'text' column that contains the full HTML of a web page.

I'd like to write a controller action that simply returns this HTML directly from the controller rather than passing it through the .erb templates like the rest of the actions on the controller.

My first thought was to pull this action into a new controller and make a custom .erb template with an empty layout, and just `<%= modelObject.htmlContent %>` in the template - but I wondered if there were a better way to do this in Rails.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In your controller `respond_to` block, you can use:

```
render :text => @model_object.html_content
```

or:

```
render :inline => "<%= @model_object.html_content %>"
```

So, something like:

```
def show
  @model_object = ModelObject.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :text => @model_object.html_content }
  end
end
```

Comment: (Sparse) documentation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Rendering.html in case anyone else is looking for it! :)

Comment: Is it really necessary to use the `respond_to` block? `render :text => '<h1>text</h1>'` works just fine for me in Rails 4. I though `respond_to` was just to deal with multiple Accept-Types.

Comment: Rails 5 yields a deprecation warning when using `render text: …`. If you want to render HTML, use `render html: …`, for text use `render plain: …`.

Answer (score 88):

In latest Rails (4.1.x), at least, this is much simpler than the accepted answer:

```
def show
  render html: '<div>html goes here</div>'.html_safe
end
```

Comment: Note that you can make it appear in the application layout like so `render html: "<p>your html</p>".html_safe, layout: 'layouts/application' `

Answer (score 4):

Its works for me

```
def show
  @model_object = ModelObject.find(params[:id])

   respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :inline => "<%== @model_object['html'] %>" }
  end
end
```