# Template is missing error when rendering html in Rails controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to use render html: to render raw html from a controller action:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def raw_html
    render html: '<html><body>Some body text</body></html>'
  end
end
```

However, when I run this controller action, I get a "Template is missing" error

I don't want to use a template, just render raw html.

The error I get is:

Processing by SomeController#raw_html as HTML
Parameters: {}
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template some_controller/raw_html
with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder,
:raw, :ruby]}. Searched in:   *
"/Users/doved/source/sample_app/app/views"   *
"/Users/doved/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@syp/gems/chameleon-0.2.4/app/views"
* "/Users/doved/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@syp/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"):
app/controllers/some_controller.rb:14:in `raw_html'

lib/middleware/cors_middleware.rb:8:in`call'

I'm using Rails 4.0.2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the server log generated + error stacktrace when you get this error.

Comment: Added the error / stack trace

Comment: What is the Rails version you using?

Comment: @KirtiThorat Added the rails version to my question

Comment: Can you share the server log generated for this action? You can get it from the terminal where you are running rails server.

Comment: @KirtiThorat the server log was already copied and pasted from my terminal added to the question.

Comment: I wanted to see the part where it goes `Processing by SomeController#raw_html......etc `.

Comment: Got it - added that part

Comment: I have posted an answer. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thanks - it must be because I was using documentation related to 4.1 but render html was not working in 4.0.2

Comment: It works perfectly in Rails 4.1. I just tried it. Just don't forget to use `html_safe` in it as suggested in answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`html` option was added to `render` method in `Rails 4.1` version.

Checkout the discussion on this topic **[on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12374)**

If you upgrade the Rails version to `Rails 4.1` then you would be able to render html as

```
def raw_html
  render html: '<html><body>Some body text</body></html>'.html_safe ## Add html_safe
end
```

With the current version of `Rails 4.0.2`, you would need to use

```
def raw_html
  render text: '<html><body>Some body text</body></html>' 
end
```

You are getting error as: `ActionView::MissingTemplate`

Because currently `html` option is not supported by `render` so the value passed with `html` option is ignored and Rails starts to look for a template `some_controller/raw_html` in views directory.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible duplicate** of

- [How to return HTML directly from a Rails controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958759/how-to-return-html-directly-from-a-rails-controller)

This should work for you:

```
render text: '<html><body>Some body text</body></html>'
```

Comment: this does work, and I could output a content type to indicate it's html, but not exactly what I want to do

Comment: actually - putting content type wasn't necessary, I was able to just render the html, and text/html came as the content type automatically