# How to add views for custom member action in active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have to add view for custom action which is member action, and want to display association records on it. Is there way to add custom view instead of just adding html.erb in admin's view folder?

I dont want to add or create html files but by using the active admins helpers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The member action in nothing else like a controller action, thats mean you can do the same things in it.

You can use thinks like:

```
render text: "Hello world!"
```

Or if you want a complex markup:

```
message1 = "Hello"
@message2 = "world!"
view = Arbre::Context.new(message: message, self) do
  h1 do
    span message
    span @message
  end
end
render body: view.to_html # or .to_s
```

Comment: its not showing html but as a tags, and without active admin layuot

Comment: Got it, `render text: view.to_s, layout: "layouts/active_admin"` worked

Comment: Having problem with above code, not able to use table_for, or paginated_collection etc. getting
undefined method `cycle' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::TableFor

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for the render html for **rails 4.1**:

```
render html: '<html><body>Some body text</body></html>'.html_safe ## Add html_safe
```

But, if you use **rails 4.2**, so you can use the following:

```
render text: '<html><body>Some body text</body></html>'
```

I think the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22975144/2791480) is very useful for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with adding the following in html.erb file in admin/user/messages.html.erb

```
<% view = Arbre::Context.new({messages: @messages, user: @user}, self) do

      panel "Sent Messages" do
        paginated_collection(messages, download_links: false) do
          table_for collection do
            column :id
            column :content            
          end
        end
      end
    end
%>

<%= view.to_s %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your namespace (ActiveAdmin is on `/admin` in my case) you can create the folder `app/views/admin` in the same way you would in the rest of your application.

For example, if you have a resource `User` and an action `apply_discount`

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  member_action :apply_discount, method: [:get, :put] do
    if request.get?
      render :apply_discount
    else
      # TODO ...
    end
  end    
end
```

you could put your ARBRE view file into `app/views/admin/users/apply_discount.html.arb` -> notice the extension is ARB, not ERB - though ERB should work too [according to the docs](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#rendering)