# Trigger modal from Controller with ruby condition

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, modalviewcontroller

I would like to trigger a modal in response to an if/else statement from my Controller.
**Here we are in the forecasts_controller.rb**

```
if @forecasts.count < 50 
 ...
else
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html {render html: "<div>My text </div>"}
 end
end
```

However, I have this error which is popping

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
```

My goal is to show a modal to the user, if he has forecasted 50 games or more.
Thanks by advance.

Comment: can you show me rails server console output? seems that view is asking for other format & controller providing different one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return HTML directly from a Rails controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958759/how-to-return-html-directly-from-a-rails-controller)

Comment: Hello, I already tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: It's exactly what my console is showing me,  nothing more unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

In your controller respond_to block, you can use:

```
render :text => @model_object.html_content
```

or:

```
render :inline => "<%= @model_object.html_content %>"
```

So, something like:

```
if @forecasts.count < 50 
 ...
else
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html {render :inline => "<div>My text </div>"}
 end
end
```

will work.

Comment: @gclement - Can you give me github URL for your code? if possible?

Comment: @gclement - Seems that you're your request which comes in the controller is expecting JSON response, but controller gives HTML response instead of JSON response.

Comment: You mean because of the line 60 ?

Comment: nope. due to this one -> format.html {render :inline => "<div>My text </div>"}

Comment: Well but my goal is to show a modal to the user, explaining he forecasted too much. How I can solve this ?

Comment: @gclement - You can send something like this instead - render json: { status: "forecasted too much" }, and handle the same in your views.

Comment: This is what I did not understand, basically. How I can send something to the view due to the condition in my controller

Comment: @gclement - You can refer this for more info - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html